# How to check the correct radio button in MFC if the tab order has been changed

Tags: visual-c++, com, mfc, radio-button, activex

I have this COM control with a group of radio buttons, which is associated with an integer variable to identify the checked radio button.

This associated variable is saved/loaded through DoPropExchange(), therefore, backward compatibility is a must, i.e. the checked radio button saved by old version should be able to be carried over to the newer version, even though in the newer version, the tab order of the radio buttons have been changed.

But after I added additional radio buttons into the group and changed the tab orders, when I was trying to load an old version of this control, there is no radio button checked! I ran it in debug mode and found that the associated integer was correctly loaded.

Thanks in advance!
James

Comment: Check the "radio button issues" section in http://www.flounder.com/guiowner.htm. I don't know if it can help you right now with your backward compatibility problem, but it gives really valuable tips on how to work with radio buttons in a maintainable way.

Comment: That's a nice article, well explained and very helpful! Many thanks, James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buttons work nice with proper group and tab order, as you mentioned. However at any time each button is still a window, with [`BM_SETCHECK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) applicable, [`CButton::SetCheck`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31deb72x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is the MFC wrapper.

You can update buttons check state invidually, esp. handling `BN_CLICKED` notification from all radio buttons and updateing check state on all other radio buttons respectively.

Something you might possibly need to correctly check a button:

```
INT m_nIndex;
// ...
// (there a power from above loads nIndex from persistent storage)
// ...
CButton* pButton1 = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIO1);
CButton* pButton2 = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIO2);
CButton* pButton3 = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIO3);
pButton1->SetCheck(m_nIndex == 0);
pButton1->SetCheck(m_nIndex == 1);
pButton1->SetCheck(m_nIndex == 2);
```

Comment: Thanks, Roman. But my problem is to deal with already saved radio button index. The correct radio button cannot get checked when loading from persistent storage. Your method can identify which button is actually clicked, but when the dialog is initialized I need to load the "index" of radio buttons and check the correct one without manually choosing the correct one. Cheers, James

Comment: I think I'd better forget about the microsoft DDX_ mechanism. It's not maintainable at all. Thanks, Roman. I think I'd better to map the index manually as you suggested.

Comment: Notice that the parameter for `SetCheck` is not a `bool`, but an `int` that can be `BST_CHECKED`, `BST_UNCHECKED` or `BST_INDETERMINATE`.

Comment: @MariusBancila: You are correct, even though `BST_CHECKED` is `0x01` and "true" constants of `1` and `-1` have the respective bit set correctly in case of two-state button. Code with `BST_xxx` is more accurate. of course.